# What happens to an SQL SELECT query if the data changes whilst the query is running

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a large database which is regularly being written to. We have a SELECT query on this DB which takes a couple of minutes to run. If we run this query and during those couple of minutes newer data is inserted/updated, will those changes be picked up by the query (assuming it matches the parameters of the query)? Or will it instead return the results as it was at run time?

Comment: The query sees a consistent view of the data.  However, such updates might put a big load on the server.

Comment: So even if its inserted whilst running it will still be returned?

Comment: The summary of answers you received is this: The `select` statement will return the data as it was at the time execution began. This includes changes made **and committed** by other sessions, as well as all changes (committed **or not**) made by **your** session, ***before*** your `select` statement began running. Any changes made after that time, even if they are committed before the query completes, will **not** be reflected in the result of the query. Also, suppose your query is very complicated, and parsing and optimization take two minutes, while execution takes five hours.

Comment: The query will reflect data as it was when **execution** begins; changes that were committed while the query was being parsed/optimized **will** be reflected by the query result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Andrew Sayers answer and link really helped. The whole time is spent in execution as far as I can tell, as the database consists of several tables with 10m+ records in each, and we then have to join several together and select a large amount of data from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Oracle: when executing a query, you will read the data as of a specific point in time to guarantee consistency. By default, that will be the time that the execution started.

Have a read about it in the Database Concepts guide  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-4D3C43F5-4EC6-4A21-9E91-8E4F33FE7790 . How Oracle achieves this is one of its features that sets it apart from most other RDBMS.

Answer (score -1):

Each query – no matter what is the underlying database – operates within a `TRANSACTION`, whether explicit or implied.  And, each transaction has a specific ["isolation level."](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)

The best strategy is to `BEGIN TRANSACTION` explicitly, but the reality is that you need to make yourself aware of what your chosen DB-interface is doing behind the scenes.  This will give you your answer.  "When you ran your query," your software did something.

Comment: Just to clarify the query I am running is a simple SELECT * based on a last_updated field being set to more recently than a specified date. I was wondering if during those 2 minutes a new record inserted (which takes less than a second) would appear in the results. I'm still not sure, but I'll keep doing research on the isolation level, thanks for the pointer in the right direction!

Comment: It doesn't matter if your query is a simple SELECT * FROM EMP; or a thousand-line monstrosity spanning a dozen (or more) tables.  You will only see the data that _was committed_ as of the SCN at the time your query began executing.  That's the whole purpose of the rollback segments.  Please read the link posted by @Andrew Sayer.

Comment: A transaction isn't started when you run a `select` statement (for the purposes of my comment, I'm excluding `select ... for update` statements here) in Oracle, because a select statement doesn't change any data or create any locks in the tables it queries. Therefore you don't need to manually start a transaction just to run a select query. In fact, I would actively advise against doing so.